# I am Creating two tables and in one of the tables I am trying to assign a foreign key but it is giving me an error

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating two tables one Platforms table and one game table and I am getting an error saying that it can not find PLATFORMID in sql statment but I don't understand why

`Column "PLATFORMID" not found; SQL statement: CREATE TABLE game( gameId LONG PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255), publisher VARCHAR(255), platform VARCHAR(255), price DECIMAL(4,2), FOREIGN KEY (platformId) REFERENCES Platforms(platformId) ) [42122-200]`

This is my code for creating my tables

```
 CREATE TABLE Platforms(
     platformId LONG PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     platformName VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE game(
    gameId LONG PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255), publisher VARCHAR(255), platform VARCHAR(255), price DECIMAL(4,2),
         FOREIGN KEY (platformId) REFERENCES Platforms(platformId)
);
```

Comment: You haven't declared a platformid column in the referencing table. PS For compiler errors chop code down as much as possible & until OK & add back. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because a `platformId` reference is not found in the `game` table.

A few things to note:

1. The `LONG` data type is an alias for `MEDIUMTEXT`, which surely would not have `AUTO_INCREMENT`? I get an error with the use as-is.
2. When you do `FOREIGN KEY (platformId)`, this portion refers to a column in the *current table*, and then the other table that this column refers to is the: `REFERENCES Platforms(platformId)` portion.
3. The foreign key's `(column)` reference in the current table must have an index.
4. It's critical to know that the column reference in BOTH tables for the foreign key must have the *same data type*, including signed-ness, if specified. (For example, if one column has unsigned, then other column needs to be unsigned too)

So, knowing those things, in the example below:

1. I've replaced `LONG` with `INT(11) unsigned` in both tables.
2. Added a column for `platformId` in the `game` table
3. Adds an index to the `platformId` column in the `game` table as well.

Putting all that together, here's an example interaction:

```
root@localhost((none)) use test2;
Database changed

root@localhost(test2) show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost(test2) CREATE TABLE Platforms(
    ->      platformId INT(11) unsigned PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->      platformName VARCHAR(255)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

root@localhost(test2) CREATE TABLE game(
    ->     gameId INT(11) unsigned PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     name VARCHAR(255),
    ->     publisher VARCHAR(255),
    ->     platform VARCHAR(255),
    ->     platformId INT(11) unsigned,
    ->     price DECIMAL(4,2),
    ->     index(platformid),
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (platformId) REFERENCES Platforms(platformId)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

root@localhost(test2) show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_test2 |
+-----------------+
| game            |
| platforms       |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost(test2) show create table game \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: game
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `game` (
  `gameId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `platformId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gameId`),
  KEY `platformId` (`platformId`),
  CONSTRAINT `game_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`platformId`) REFERENCES `platforms` (`platformId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```